# Customize returning JSON from ASP.NET Core API , Values with Statuscode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to return back JSON with customization , anyone can help to return the result like this :

```
{
    status: 200,
    message: "success",
    data: {
        var1: {
        },
        var2: {
        }
    }
}
```

with this code :

```
            return Ok(new
            {
                var1,
                var2
            });
```

Comment: a custom middleware would do it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use the OkResult object?

A simple way of returning what you'd like is to use dynamic objets, or a class with properties matching the Json you'd like to get, and a JsonResult object.

```
             dynamic json = new ExpandoObject();
             json.Result = 200;
             json.Message = "success";
             json.Data.var1 = "whatever";
             json.Data.var2 = "something else";

             Response.StatusCode = json.Result; //matches the HTTP Status Code with the one from your json
                return new JsonResult(json);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I fixed what I want , I ll post in an answer below

Answer (score 0):

I used this for taking profile information from google id token , and then generate JWT token from my backend server and retuen back JWT and Profile info for client apps so this is the solution :

```
var profile = (new RetrnedUserProfile
            {
                Email = payload.Email,
                FirstName = payload.GivenName,
                FamilyName = payload.FamilyName,
                PictureUrl = payload.Picture
            });

            return Ok(new ResponseModel
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Message = "success",

                Data = new
                {
                    profile,
                    accessToken
                }
            });

 public class RetrnedUserProfile
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseModel
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```